# timestamptoken validate java bouncycastle

Tags: java, timestamp, bouncycastle, x509, trusted-timestamp

I used BouncyCastle to verify signature and extract infos from a ".p7m" file (original content, signer etc.).

Now I need to validate and extract infos from the TimeStamp within the same ".p7m" file.

How can I validate the TimeStampToken? I wrote this code that works well for the Signature but it doesn't validate the TimeStamp. I passed the "cert" variable to the build() method to validate the Signature and the TimeStampToken both. For the Signature it's ok, but for the TimeStamp it doesn't work :(

Where do I wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Encodable;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.cms.Attribute;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.cms.AttributeTable;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PKCSObjectIdentifiers;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.X509CertificateHolder;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSException;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSProcessable;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedData;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedDataParser;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformation;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformationStore;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.tsp.TimeStampToken;
import org.bouncycastle.util.Store;

public class Launcher3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        File myFile=new File("D:\\fdr\\bouncycastle\\New Text Document.txt.p7m");
        byte[] bytesArray = readContentIntoByteArray(myFile);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\fdr\\bouncycastle\\New Text Document.txt");
        byte[] bytesArrayOriginalFile=getData(bytesArray);
        fos.write(bytesArrayOriginalFile);
        fos.close();

        verifySign(bytesArray);

    }

    static public void verifySign(byte[] signedData) throws Exception {
          Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

          CMSSignedDataParser     sp = new CMSSignedDataParser(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(), signedData);

          sp.getSignedContent().drain();

          Store                   certStore = sp.getCertificates();
          SignerInformationStore  signers = sp.getSignerInfos();

          Collection              c = signers.getSigners();
          Iterator                it = c.iterator();

          while (it.hasNext())
          {
              SignerInformation   signer = (SignerInformation)it.next();
              Collection          certCollection = certStore.getMatches(signer.getSID());
              Iterator        certIt = certCollection.iterator();
              X509CertificateHolder cert = (X509CertificateHolder)certIt.next();

              System.out.println("info 1: "+cert.getIssuer());
              System.out.println("info 2: "+cert.getSubject());
              System.out.println("date from: "+cert.getNotBefore());
              System.out.println("date to: "+cert.getNotAfter());
              System.out.println("Serial n. "+cert.getSerialNumber());
              System.out.println("verify returns: " + signer.verify(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(cert)));
              // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
              // LOOK AT HERE: it works!

              AttributeTable       attrs = signer.getUnsignedAttributes();
              Attribute            att = attrs.get(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.id_aa_signatureTimeStampToken); 
              ASN1Encodable        dob = att.getAttrValues().getObjectAt(0);
              byte[] encodedTsp = dob.toASN1Primitive().getEncoded();

              TimeStampToken result = null;

              if(encodedTsp!=null) {
                  CMSSignedData cms = new CMSSignedData(encodedTsp);
                  result = new TimeStampToken(cms);

                System.out.println("timestamp: "+result.getTimeStampInfo().getGenTime());
                System.out.println("serial n. "+result.getTimeStampInfo().getSerialNumber());
                System.out.println("tsa: "+result.getTimeStampInfo().getTsa());
                System.out.println("policy: "+result.getTimeStampInfo().getPolicy());

                result.validate(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(cert));
                // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
                // LOOK AT HERE: it doesn't work!

                } 
          }
    }

    static public byte[] getData(final byte[] p7bytes) throws CMSException, IOException  {
        CMSSignedData signedData = new CMSSignedData(p7bytes);
        CMSProcessable signedContent = signedData.getSignedContent();

        return (byte[])signedContent.getContent();

       }

        private static byte[] readContentIntoByteArray(File file)
       {
          FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
          byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];
          try
          {
             fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
             fileInputStream.read(bFile);
             fileInputStream.close();
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return bFile;
       }

}
```

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Is it throwing an exception?

Comment: Sorry, the problem is that I checked the wrong certificate and the error was:
`Exception in thread "main" org.bouncycastle.tsp.TSPValidationException: certificate hash does not match certID hash.`. I solved!

Answer (score 2):

I solved by myself (and I'm so happy). I need to find the certificate of the timestamptoken in this way:

```
Store storeTt = result.getCertificates();
Collection collTt = storeTt.getMatches(result.getSID());
Iterator certIt2 = collTt.iterator();
X509CertificateHolder cert2 = (X509CertificateHolder)certIt2.next();

System.out.println("timestamp's verify: "+result.isSignatureValid(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(cert2)));
result.validate(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(cert2));
```